# Error not being logged into output log file

Tags: powershell

I have the following script where, when the `if(-not)` condition is met, the log file is being generated but not error is being written in the log file.

I have very basic understanding of scripting languages and as a result cannot understand why nothing is being logged. Help is appreciated.

```
$resulterror = $error[0].exception.message
$BckDate = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
$BckFolder = "<path>"+$BckDate
$log = "<path>"+$BckDate+".log"'

Copy-Item -Path $BckFolder -Destination <drive-letter> -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse

if(-not $?) {$resulterror >> $log ; invoke-expression -Command "<path-of-ps-script-to-run>"}

else {"Backup "+$BckDate+" done successfully" >> $log}
```

The real paths have been hidden with the "path" in <> explaining that it is a directory path.

The path of the script triggered when the if(-not) condition is met is replaced with path-of-ps-script-to-run in <>. The <> are just brackets for the comments so don't confuse them with actual code symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `-ErrorVariable` advanced parameter to store the error message in that variable and access it:

```
Copy-Item -Path $BckFolder -Destination <drive-letter> -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse -ErrorVariable copyError
if($copyError)
{
    $resulterror | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
    invoke-expression -Command "<path-of-ps-script-to-run>"
}
else 
{
    "Backup "+$BckDate+" done successfully" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **$resulterror** is empty since you saved it at the very begining of the script and there were no errors at that time. Try to use explicit **$error[0].exception.message** instead of $resulterror on IF condition.

```
$BckDate = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy"
$BckFolder = "<path>"+$BckDate
$log = "<path>"+$BckDate+".log"

Copy-Item -Path $BckFolder -Destination <drive-letter> -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse

if(-not $?) {$error[0].exception.message >> $log ; invoke-expression -Command "<path-of-ps-script-to-run>"}

else {"Backup "+$BckDate+" done successfully" >> $log}
```